# Libgdx i18nbundle work only root bundle

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

*English isn't my first language.*
In mobile i18nbundle get only root bundle (BlueStacks similarly). 
Code :

```
Locale locale = new Locale("eng");
I18NBundle myBundle = I18NBundle.createBundle(Gdx.files.internal("Text/Text"), locale);
TextButton textButton = new TextButton(myBundle.format("testText"),skin)
```

I have there : "Text.properties" and "Text_eng.properties" but only "Text.properties" works.
All work fine in the IDEA.
Mobile : JiaYu G4 , API - 17

Change to code to :

```
Locale locale = new Locale("eng","Test","Test");
I18NBundle myBundle = I18NBundle.createBundle(Gdx.files.internal("Text/Text"), locale);
TextButton textButton = new TextButton(myBundle.format("testText"),skin)
```

Now load on PC "Text_eng_Test_Test.properties". On mobile "Text_eng_Test.properties".

Comment: You may also want to provide device related information and what version of Andriod you are running.

Comment: Kalagen - add mobile model and API